# How to prevent name mangling of javascript functions in django-pipeline

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-pipeline, yuglify

I am using django version 1.82 with django-pipeline. I call a particular javascript function from html by name.

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right vcenter" 
 action="javascript:search();" role="search" id='searchform'>
```

Unfortunately in the compressed js file, the name of the function is changed and hence the frontend functionality is not workig.  How do I maintain the same name for that function or how do I change the reference to the js function in html?

I have installed yuglify and the settings I use is

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
'allstyles': {
    'source_filenames': (
      'css/application.css',
      'feedback/css/feedback-form.css',
    ),
    'output_filename': 'css/nifty.css',
    'extra_context': {
        'media': 'screen,projection',
    },
},
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
'actions': {
    'source_filenames': (
      'js/nifty.js',
      'feedback/js/feedback-form.js',
    ),
    'output_filename': 'js/nifty.js',
}
}
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
PIPELINE_DISABLE_WRAPPER = True
PIPELINE_ENABLED=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `search()` is a global function? To make sure you can assign it to the `window` variable:

```
window.search = function() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it the other way around.

```
<form ... action="/nojs.html" ... id='searchform'>
```

and then intercept the `submit` event on the form.

```
(function(){
    var sf = document.getElementById('searchform');
    sf.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        // do here whatever "search()" needs to do
    });
})();
```

That way you don't need to add anything into the `window` namespace, are independent of minified function names, and a browser with disabled JS gets a readable error page.